# TrafficStats API giving different values on different API level?

Tags: android, android-networking

In my application I'm uploading a file of size **4MB** to a Server. I'm monitoring the bytes transmitted by my app using method `getUidTxBytes(int uid)`. Following are my observations :

**API 18 and Above**

The total bytes i transmit is always greater than 4MB(Egs : 4.27 MB), so I'm assuming that it's the total of my Payload + Headers.

**API 17 and Below**

The total bytes i transmit is always equal to 4MB(Egs : 4.0003 MB), so I'm assuming that it's the total of my Payload alone.

Why is there a difference between the bytes calculated on different API level?

Comment: Note that `getUidTxBytes()` is not transactional and will include anything your process does between measurements. Are you sure that nothing else is going on inside your process that might only be kicking in in API Level 18+? It looks like `TrafficStats` underwent some changes in API Level 18 (bunch of stuff deprecated), so it's entirely possible that what you are seeing is an actual change in `TrafficStats` behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the quick response. I'm sure that only that particular transaction is taking place in my app. On every second I'm measuring `getUidTxBytes()` and the amount of data which this API is giving me is equal to the amount of data that I'm writing on `OutputStream` whereas in API 18+ this value is always greater than what I'm writing in `OutputStream` which seems to be correct as it should be Payload + Header bytes.

Comment: Yeah, but 0.27MB seems like an awful lot of header bytes. Your headers are really 1/16th the size of the file?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply but I've tested it on different OEM's and it's showing the exact behavior for all of them. The headers I'm getting is still different for different API's. Is there any implementation difference below API 18 and above?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but `TrafficStats`' implementation must be pretty low level.